# When to use date plugin in logstash,what is the use of it?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

i am novice to ES and having a field tran_timestamp yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss in file to be uploaded . I am confused how to upload it in ES? Should i replace the value of existing  @timestamp with this value or should ingest it separate as date .
As i have to do analysis on time basis.Kindly suggest .

Comment: The role of the `date` filter is to parse date fields and use them as the event timestamp. So it's your call to know whether `tran_timestamp` should be considered your event timestamp or if you have other dates, which would be better suited to be the event timestamp. One thing is sure, though, if you have a date, you better ingest it as a date, so you can leverage date histogram and ranges later on.

Comment: @Val Thanks val for quick response.1 more question if i don't replace event timestamp with my csv date,would i be still able to create date histogram ?

Comment: Yes, because a default @timestamp will be created at the time your event is processed, so you'll always have a date field in your events that you can use.

Comment: @val Thanks . I would ingest both the fields timestamp (which will have record insertion time) and tran_timestamp(which will have actual value in csv).As this tran_time_stamp field in CSV is currently being loaded as string i want to insert it as date now .Please suggest how to achieve that through convert API in mutate?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our exchange in the comments above, you can simply add a `date` filter like this with a `target` property to store the date field into after being parsed:

```
filter {
   ... other filters ...

   date {
      match => ["tran_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
      target => "tran_timestamp"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi val some more doubts, 1) Can't i achieve it through convert in mutate ? 2) what will happen if I remove the target ?

Comment: No, date is the only filter allowing you to parse dates. Is there a problem using the date filter?

Comment: No , but was bit confused,I thought it's just to change value for timestamp of insertion time.

Comment: If you remove the target, the parsed date will be stored in `@timestamp` instead. target allows you to store the parsed date in any other arbitrary field. I agree my first comment might have been troubling. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ Val Thanks Once again.